# How to exit from QThread if I have infinite loop inside run method

Tags: python, pyqt4, qthread

Have such run method:

```
def run(self):
    while True:
        new_value = self.client.read_holding_registers(self.reg_num, 1, unit=self.slave_id).registers[0]
        if new_value != self.value:
            self.value = new_value
            self.data_changed.emit(
                {"id": "{0};{1};{2};{3}".format(self.host, self.port, self.slave_id, self.reg_num),
                 "value": self.value})
            self.usleep(100)
```

So i need to catch the upcoming data from the connection. And I don't have condition to break this loop (only if connection is broken). So how I have to terminate from my thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you familiar with what a [daemon](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/daemons) is? If you want your thread to always run and exit when your whole application stops then you need to make it a daemon.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to control starting and stopping my thread. If I want to create aroung 100 of this threads to run infinite, what technology have I use?

Comment: when do you want to stop them and how? Do you want to manually select and stop 1 at a time? I suggested the daemon approach since you can spawn 100 of them in your main function and then when you close your application it will automatically close all the daemon threads.

Comment: I want to stop them from the interface button (start/stop). Yes, I want to select and stop 1 at a time. But I think there is a problem with a daemon, that I can't emit signal to transfer data to the interface. Or can?) As I know, you can only make signal in a class that inherits QObject. So I need to create class that inhertits run.Daemon (from [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/daemons)) and QObject?

Comment: In your case you don't need daemon threads. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python) is something I found useful. You basically make a custom thread that before it runs it checks for a condition. Instead of `while True` you do something like `while self.isStillGoodToRun`. When you want the thread to stop you just call the `stop()` method on it. Your stop method should just set that thread specific variable (`self.isStillGoodToRun`) to `False`.

Comment: Also make sure that variable is local to the thread and not shared since it could terminate all 100 simultaneously.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think that i helped. Very interesting and simple solution.

Comment: Do you mean the locality of the variable `self.isStillGoodToRun`?

Comment: I found [something](http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/Multithread/python_multithreading_Thread_Local_Specific_Data.php) that might explain what I meant. Sorry for not providing in depth explanations and just giving links. I am not home right now. Since you will make 100 threads you need to make sure they don't use the same isStillGoodToRun. I am not really sure when it is hidden from other threads and when it is not but local() seems to do the job. I just want to make sure threadA.isStillGoodToRun can be False while threadB.isStillGoodToRun can be True at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I am pretty sure that my threads are running pretty separate and I will not have such issue.